# Is there an app or setting to lock an iPad in a Presentation mode, so other apps can't be accessed?

Tags: ipad

Not really an iPad user so thought I would ask here.

As an organisation we want to place some presentations on iPad minis 
(much in the way that iPads are used in the Apple Stores as information sources next to other products).

We want the user to be incentivised to view the entire presentation so ideally we don't want them to be able to leave the presentation.

Are there any applications that allow presentations to be locked?
Ideally, presentations would be built in PowerPoint or HTML/CSS.

I appreciate any input you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple-sanctioned method to accomplish this is the use of the [Guided Access](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/25/enable-guided-access-ios/) feature in iOS6. Settings > General > Accessibility > Learning > Guided Access.

Comment: Close.  Should be  Settings > General > Accessibility ...

Comment: Fixed main body of answer. Thanx GEdgar.

Comment: thats superb news, so I can build a powerpoint presentation and then lock the screen with guided access?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has not (yet) released Office 20xx for iOS, so the Powerpoint presentation needs to be opened and certified in Apple's Keynote on a OSX Mac. You can then present on the iPad with Keynote for iOS. RTFM the Keynote dox as there are [some things to take into consideration](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4114) when building a presentation on OSX to be used on iOS.

If the presentation is not interactive (i.e., the presenter just talks over pre-timed slides w/out manual advancing,) then perhaps exporting a movie file of the presentation and showing it in the Video app would be the simplest solution.